# python subprocess.run() returns AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspberry-pi, subprocess, gammu

I'm trying to execute a shell command from a python script. I'm using python 3.7.3, so the run() function should work properly, but it always throws the
`AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'run'` Error. I set the default version of python to 3.7.3. `python --version` also returns `Python 3.7.3`. In order to understand the problem I wrote a simple script called out.py:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import subprocess
subprocess.run(["ls", "-l"])
```

If I execute this script from the shell with `sudo python out.py` it returns the above mentioned error. If I execute it with `sudo python3 out.py` it works just fine. Am I missing something here? I`ve never used python2 in the first place. Note: I'm doing this on a Raspberry Pi. The script where I want to execute the shell command from is invoked as part of a trigger routine, so I don't know if I can change something there (Gammu RunOnReceive directive)

Comment: I'm not in Linux currently, i ran equivalent command `dir` using this in windows 10, and it worked fine

Comment: `python` is mapped to python2 in your system. At least as user `root`. When you run `python --version` you will get the deafult interpreter for your user. Run `sudo python --version` and you will see that he uses python2.

Comment: @WasifHasan the code from above does not represent the shell command I want to execute. It's more about the general problem of the subprocess.run() function returning the error, even if I don't run it with python 2

Comment: @fuuman how can I fix this? I set the alias of python to python3. How can i accomplish this for the root user?

Comment: That's entirely a different question, and not hard to google. Here, I spent 10 seconds: https://superuser.com/questions/1220872/how-can-i-pass-an-alias-to-sudo ... But aliases suck; probably try to unlearn them.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed my issue by setting the python version of the root user to python3